# Every graph $G$ has a bipartite subgraph $H$ in which every vertex has at least half of the degree as in original graph.

Tags: graph-theory

Every graph $G$ has a bipartite subgraph $H$ in which every vertex has at least half of the degree as in original graph.
I was able to prove the weaker version that the bipartite subgraph will have atleast half no of edges as in $G$, but I am not getting an idea on how to prove this stronger version?

Answer (score 2):

Arbitrarily assign the vertices to two parts. Then successively switch vertices to the other part if they do not have half the vertices they had in $G$.

Each switch will increase the number of edges in the reduced graph, since the number of edges lost is less than the number of edges gained. As long as any such switch is possible the number of edges can be increased again by switching. Clearly there is a maximum to the number of edges - the edge count in $G$ - so this process must terminate with an $H$ in which all vertices have degree at least half the value in $G$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: if some vertex doesn't satisfy this, try moving it to the other part of the bipartite graph.